# jQuery trigger click endless loop

Tags: jquery

why is this jQuery code endlessly looping as soon as the line

> //$('.'+triggerThisChild).trigger("click"); // this causes endless
>   loop

is uncommented [FIDDLE is here](http://jsfiddle.net/xjtZd/)

jQuery code:

```
$('a.touchNav').on('click touchend', function (e) {
    var fancy = this.className.indexOf('fancy') != -1;
    var target = $(this).attr('target') == '_blank' ? true : false;
    if (fancy) {
        var triggerThisChild = $(this).children('span').attr('class');
        alert(triggerThisChild);
        e.stopPropagation();
        //$('.'+triggerThisChild).trigger("click"); // this causes endless loop
        //return false;
    } else if (target) {
        window.open(this.href,target);
        return false;
    } else {
       window.location = this.href;
       return false;
    }
});

$(".showFancyBox").fancybox({
    "width" : "75%",
    "height" : 800,
    "transitionIn" : "none",
    "transitionOut" : "none",
    "type" : "iframe",
    'href' : "http://www.google.com"
});
```

HTML:

```
<li>
<a class="touchNav" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    Nav Point 1
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="touchNav" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
    Nav Point 2
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="fancy touchNav" href="#">
    <span class="showFancy0" style="display:none;"></span>
    Nav Point 3
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The click event on `.showFancy0` bubbles up to the parent `a` and the whole thing runs again.

Add this code to stop it happening...

```
$(".showFancy0").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjtZd/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The `click` event you trigger on the element's children will bubble up, and trigger again the `click` callback you placed on the element itself.

In the code you show, there is nothing to stop a click event from bubbling up from a `'.'+triggerThisChild` element.

Rather than triggering a click event, I would put the relevant code in an separate function, and call that function from both handlers. e.g :

rather than :

```
$('.showFancy0').on('click', function(e) {
       //code to display fancybox
});

$('a.touchNav').on('click touchend', function(e){
     if (conditions) {
        $('.showFancy0').trigger('click');
     }
});
```

write :

```
function showFancyBox(/* any arguments you need */) {
   //code to show fancybox
}

$('.showFancy0').on('click', function(e) {
       showFancyBox(/* get the arguments and pass them */);
});

$('a.touchNav').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    if (conditions) {
       showFancyBox(/* get the arguments and pass them */);
    }
});
```

Comment: with $('.'+triggerThisChild).trigger("click"); I'm trying to open up an iframe fancybox

Answer (score 1):

You're triggering a click event inside of an onClick function. So any time you click an element that triggers the function, it's effectively calling the same function over and over again.